# Breezejs SaveChanges error.detail is undefined for OptimisticConcurrencyException

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

As shown in following picture,on concurrency exception,saveChanges fail function give me no detail prop in error obj.

After searching, found that i need to set customerrors to off in web config.however in prod server or localhost there is no available way to get detail prop.
When i dig into the error prop,i found concurrency exception in inner exception of inner exception but detail property of error obj still undefined.

Please let me know the point im missing.

im using mvc app with webapi2 with vs2013

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the required properties of your entities are all being set, especially the Id or whatever foreign key fields?

This sounds like an entity framework error being thrown which should be in the httpResponse object in your screen shot but the better solution would be to debug the server and see what is causing it.

You could check your save payload for the problem or set a breakpoint on the server to check further.

Answer (score 0):

honestly waht im trying to get to test the following code in saveError method of saveChanges.What im trying is just to open the same entity in different tab of browser and delete both.Second delete actually give me the System.Exception in server with concurrent exception in innerexception.However detail prop is undefined.

```
  var reason = error.message;
        var detail = error.detail;

        if (error.entityErrors) {
            reason = this.handleSaveValidationError(error);
        } else if (detail && detail.ExceptionType &&
            detail.ExceptionType.indexOf('OptimisticConcurrencyException') !== -1) {
            // Concurrency error 
            reason =
                "Another user, perhaps the server, " +
                "may have deleted one or all of the todos." +
                " You may have to restart the app.";
        } else {
            reason = "Failed to save changes: " + reason +
                " You may have to restart the app.";
        }
```

this is the response i get from server after savechanges

[image]